# All actions are inactive in Opscenter

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, opscenter

I have a Cassandra 2 cluster of 6 nodes. I successfully installed Opscenter 5 & Datastax-agents. The agents are connected to Opscenter and all run smoothly except for the all cluster actions: rebalance, repair etc. All these options are inactive in the interface. What's going wrong?
[image: Opscenter inactive actions]

Answer (score 3):

You said you are running Cassandra; the features you see as inactive are for Datastax Enterprise clusters only.

At the bottom of this page is the list of Enterprise-only features:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/features_c.html